# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Feature>'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying First filter list and then using `OrderBy` but I'm getting following error on the `Where` clause

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

What's wrong with my query?

```
Offer internetOffer = offerList
                      .Where(x => (x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet) 
                      && (x.FeatureList
                          .Where(y => y.FeatureName == Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME)))
                          .OrderByDescending(y => y.Value);
```

Comment: `&& (x.FeatureList.Where(y => y.FeatureName == Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME)` did you meant `any`?

Comment: You have the answer here : https://forums.asp.net/t/2065524.aspx?Operator+cannot+be+applied+to+operands+of+type+bool+and+System+Collections+Generic+IEnumerable+bool+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x.FeatureList.Where(...)` produces an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` of items in `FeatureList` that match the criteria. Since you are looking for a condition to see if there are any such items, use `x.FeatureList.Any(...)` instead:

```
Offer internetOffer = offerList
    .Where(x =>
             (x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet) 
          && (x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == 
              Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME))
           ).OrderByDescending(y => y.Value);
```

> can you please tell how can I get the item from this list whose `FeatureName` is `Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME` and have the Max value of property `Value`?

Add `FirstOrDefault` to the call above:

```
Offer bestInternetOffer = offerList
    .Where(x =>
             (x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet) 
          && (x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == 
              Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME))
           )
           .OrderByDescending(y => y.Value)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `OrDefault` part will protect your code from crashing when none of the offers has a feature named `DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME`.

Comment: Okay but then I want to `OrderByDescending` by value of that `Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME` feature. This query wont get me that. Right?

Comment: @HumaAli Right, `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` apply to the overall list, not to any sub-lists. You can select ordered features with or without applying additional criteria, but `x.FeatureList` collections will remain ordered in their natural order.

Comment: can you please tell how can I get the item from this list whose FeatureName is `Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME` and have the Max value of property `Value`?

Answer (score 2):

Where returns an IEnumerable not a boolean, simply replace Where with Any

```
... x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == Const.CommonConstant.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME)))....
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
x.FeatureList.Where(y => y.FeatureName == Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME)
```

returns a `IEnumerable<Feature>` instead of a `boolean` value.

assuming you want to check if there exists `Any()` you have to replace it by

```
x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == Const.CommonConstants.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME)
```