# OrderBy using WHERE in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List `offerList` of type `Offer`

```
public class Offer
{
    public List<Feature> FeatureList { get; set; }

}

public class Feature
{
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the `Offer` and whose `FeatureName` is "Int" with max max of the property `Value` . I tried the following LINQ
but it gives error

> Offer' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension
>   method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'Offer' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
List<Offer> offerList = resp;
Offer filteredOffer = offerList
    .Where(x => x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet)
    .Where(x => x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == "INT"))
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are ordering a list of Offer objects which only have the FeatureList property

Comment: @LiviuBoboia check edited post

Comment: i'm guessing that your offerList is a List<Offer> which again does not have a property called Value

Comment: What you want ?

Comment: The result of `Where` is an `IEnumerable` of `Offer` and `Offer` has no `Value`. Do you want to get an `Offer` with the highest `Value` among all `Offer`s in `offerList`?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I want Offer which has highest value of `Feature.Value` whose `Feature.Name` is 'INT'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that the inner `FeatureList` contains objects with a property `Value` and you expect that only one object has the desired `FeatureName` and you want to order by it's `Value`:

```
List<Offer> offerList = resp
   .Where(x => x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet)
   .Select(x => new 
   {
       Offer = x,   
       SpeedFeature = x.FeatureList
           .Where(y => y.FeatureName == "INT")
           .OrderByDescending(y => y.Value)
           .FirstOrDefault()
   })
   .Where(x => x.SpeedFeature != null)
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.SpeedFeature.Value)
   .Select(x => x.Offer)
   .ToList();
```

If you want the single `Offer` with the highest value replace `ToList` with `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I suspect this won't do what the OP wants. your inner `FirstOrDefault` has no guarentee it's going to return the feature that has the biggest value.

Comment: @caesay: good point, edited. But maybe this isn't needed because there is always only one feature with `FeatureName == DOWNLOAD_SPEED_FEATURE_NAME`

Comment: how do you know there will always only be one feature with that name?

Comment: @caesay: i thought so because of a comment to the accepted answer of his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491477/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-bool-and-system-collectio#comment74037897_43491533 But it might be a misunderstanding. Now my answer works in any way. I thought `FeatureName` is the unique identifier of the feature

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Offer> offerList = resp;
Offer filteredOffer = offerList
    .Where(x => x.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet)
    .Where(x => x.FeatureList.Any(y => y.FeatureName == "INT"))
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.FeatureList.Where(x => x.FeatureName == "INT").Max(u => u.Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you're after:

```
List<Offer> offerList = resp;
var filteredQuery = from offer in offerList
                    where offer.VerticalType == VerticalType.HighSpeedInternet
                    from feature in offer.FeatureList
                    where feature.FeatureName == "INT"
                    orderby feature.Value desc
                    select new { offer, feature };

Offer filteredOffer = filteredQuery.FirstOrDefault()?.offer;
```

It will search for the single highest valued `INT` feature and return the feature and offer to which it belongs.